# mysql passing select result into another query

Tags: mysql

I am not an expert of mysql and came across the following scenario.

I have 3 following tables, article, tag and articles_tags, tried to describe table definition in minimal possible manner.

```
article: id
tag: id
articles_tags: article_id, tag_id
```

Now I needed to do following

1. get all tags
2. then articles of each tag from step 1.
3. then again get all tags of each article from step 2, then group them based on their occurrences and get final result as json.

   for example tag named whatsapp, below result will in one line.

   whatsApp,
   WhatsAppDisplay, `[{“slug”:“messenger”,“displayName”:“Messenger”,“frequency”:159},{“slug”:“apps”,“displayName”:“Apps”,“frequency”:148},{“slug”:“chat”,“displayName”:“Chat”,“frequency”:109},{“slug”:“smartphone”,“displayName”:“Smartphone”,“frequency”:79},{“slug”:“iphone”,“displayName”:“iPhone”,“frequency”:54},{“slug”:“app”,“displayName”:“App”,“frequency”:53},{“slug”:“android”,“displayName”:“Android”,“frequency”:27},{“slug”:“handy”,“displayName”:“Handy”,“frequency”:26},{“slug”:“sprueche”,“displayName”:“Spr\u00fcche”,“frequency”:25},{“slug”:“ios”,“displayName”:“iOS”,“frequency”:25},{“slug”:“facebook”,“displayName”:“Facebook”,“frequency”:24},{“slug”:“nachrichten”,“displayName”:“Nachrichten”,“frequency”:22},{“slug”:“bilder”,“displayName”:“Bilder”,“frequency”:20},{“slug”:“android-smartphone”,“displayName”:“Android-Smartphone”,“frequency”:16},{“slug”:“kontakte”,“displayName”:“Kontakte”,“frequency”:15}]`

for this I wrote following sql query.

```
    SELECT t3.slug as testSlug, t3.display_name AS displayName,
    (
        SELECT CONCAT('[', second_json, ']') AS final_json FROM
            (
                SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('{', first_json, '}' SEPARATOR ',') AS second_json FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            CONCAT
                                (
                                '"slug":'   , '"', t2.slug   , '"', ',' 
                                '"displayName":', '"', t2.display_name, '"', ','
                                '"frequency":'  , count(t2.slug)
                                ) AS first_json FROM tipps.tag t2 
                                INNER JOIN tipps.articles_tags ats2 ON ats2.tag_id = t2.id
                                INNER JOIN tipps.article a2 ON a2.id = ats2.article_id
                                WHERE a2.id IN (
                                    SELECT a.id FROM tipps.tag t
                                    INNER JOIN tipps.articles_tags ats ON ats.tag_id = t.id
                                    INNER JOIN tipps.article a ON a.id = ats.article_id
                                    WHERE t.slug = 'whatsapp'
                                )
                                AND t2.slug != 'whatsapp'
                                GROUP BY t2.slug
                                ORDER BY count(t2.slug) DESC
                                LIMIT 15
                    ) AS third_json
            ) AS fourth_json
    ) AS relatedTags
FROM tipps.tag t3
LIMIT 1;
FROM tipps.tag t3 LIMIT 1;
```

For those who are really feeling hard to understand the query. Please find below simple version.

```
    /* step 2 find all tags belongs to each article */
    SELECT 
    t2.slug, 
    count(t2.slug) AS frequency 
FROM tipps.tag t2 
    INNER JOIN tipps.articles_tags ats2 ON ats2.tag_id = t2.id
    INNER JOIN tipps.article a2 ON a2.id = ats2.article_id
WHERE a2.id IN (

        /* step one find all articles belongs to a tag */
        SELECT a.id 
        FROM tipps.tag t
            INNER JOIN tipps.articles_tags ats ON ats.tag_id = t.id
            INNER JOIN tipps.article a ON a.id = ats.article_id
        WHERE t.slug = 'whatsapp'


    )

/* group them based on their occurances and sort based on occurances */
GROUP BY t2.slug
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 15;
```

As it can be seen that, I used whatsapp as constant, now is it possible to pass t3.tipps instead of constant. So that I can select all results in one query. Or is there any better approach for this. Any help or clue would be great.

Comment: The thing which appears to be a description of your table structures is incomplete. The description of how you want to query your data is incomplete - there's something very wrong if you want to read the entire dataset every time you access the data. You shouldn't be using concat like that in your query, Do not try to use nested SQL select statements to represent your JSON structure. Start again with a better problem statement.

Comment: Thank you for feedback, well I tried to explain in my best possible way. May be I need to attach a visual image to represent it. But I wrote what is the problem definition in steps and in regards to table structures its sufficient. Anyway it all depends on individual perception. Is it helps if I post the php script that is doing this operation? Its extremely slow and want to replace that with sql.

Comment: @symcbean please find the description, I added more details to it.

Answer (score 0):

We want to get all articles of a tag and all tags of those articles. This is a raw way to get all the data you need:

```
select article.id as article_id, tag.id as first_tag_id, article_tags2.tag_id as second_tag_id
from tag
join article_tags article_tags1
on tag.id = article_tags1.tag_id
join article
on article_tags1.article_id = article.id
join article_tags article_tags2
on article.id = article_tags2.article_id
```

Now that we have all tags and all articles for each tag and all tags for each article, we can group our results:

```
select article.id as article_id, tag.id as first_tag_id, article_tags2.tag_id as second_tag_id
from tag
join article_tags article_tags1
on tag.id = article_tags1.tag_id
join article
on article_tags1.article_id = article.id
join article_tags article_tags2
on article.id = article_tags2.article_id
group by tag.id, article.id
```

and from here you can do your `group_concat` and other calculations on the proper groups.